How do you put environment variable POSTGRES_PASSWORD into Dockerfile without using docker-compose?
My files:
postgresql_data/data/init.table.csv
id,name,completed
1,Buy pen,false
2,Write letter,false
3,Post letter,false
4,Post letter,false

docker-compose.yml
services:
  postgres-example-pg-hba:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_USER=mysuperuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
          - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

Dockerfile
FROM postgres:latest

# copy-data.sh
COPY ./postgresql_data ./temp

# Copy init.table.csv to /var/lib/postgresql/data/init.table.csv 
#   - Wait for postgres build to have created folder: /var/lib/postgresql/data 
#   - Then on docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/copy-data.sh
COPY ./scripts/copy-data.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/copy-data.sh
# cp /temp/data/init.table.csv -u /var/lib/postgresql/data/init.table.csv 

# Initialise database with a create table
COPY ./scripts/seed.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(
#   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
#   name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
#   completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL
# );
# COPY mytable FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/init.table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;


This works with docker-compose up --build
docker-compose up -d --build
docker exec -it dockerise-postgres-postgres-example-pg-hba-1 psql -U mysuperuser -d mydb
select * from mytable;

output
 id |     name     | completed
----+--------------+-----------
  1 | Buy pen      | f
  2 | Write letter | f
  3 | Post letter  | f
  4 | Post letter  | f
(4 rows)

This does NOT work when I do docker build . first then docker-compose up
docker-compose down
docker image rm postgres

docker build .
docker-compose up
docker exec -it dockerise-postgres-postgres-example-pg-hba-1 psql -U mysuperuser -d mydb
select * from mytable;


mydb=# select * from mytable;
ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from mytable;


How to use secrets in Docker Compose

Manage sensitive data with Docker secrets

@phuzi - thanyou phuzi. I have read those pages and the examples provided suggest using docker swarm secrets. Secrets can be used in docker-compose.yml only if using docker stack deploy. docker stack deploy does NOT prebuild the image. Hence my question to ensure I can pre-build the image and then run docker stack deploy.

If you docker compose exec postgres-example-pg-hba env | grep PG, are the normal PostgreSQL environment variables like $PGPASSWORD set in both cases?  I wouldn't expect the two paths you show to act differently.  (Note that setting image: to the Dockerfile's base image can cause unusual problems, because each build will start from the result of the previous build, but given what you show that's probably not the problem here.)

@DavidMaze PG_MAJOR=16
PG_VERSION=16.3-1.pgdg120+1
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data

@DavidMaze - you just solved my problem. I removed the image: from docker-compose and it fixed it

@DavidMaze if you want to add the answer I'll tick it

@DavidMaze - ok I realised a problem now. Removing the image from docker-compose means I can't do docker stack deploy. I get error: failed to create service secret_test_postgres-example-pg-hba: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided

For now I resolved my problem by just building an image first with docker build -t someimage:tag, then editing the docker-compose.yml to refer to this image, then docker stack deploy. While it doesn't answer my question regarding supplying environment variables in Dockerfile it is a workaround for the moment.
